# At $z=0$ the function $f(z)=\exp({z\over 1-\cos z})$ has

Tags: complex-analysis

At $z=0$ the  function $f(z)=\exp({z\over 1-\cos z})$ has

$1$. A removable singualrity

$2$. A pole

$3$. An essential singularity

$4$. Laurent series around $z=0$ has infinitely man positive and negative power of $z$

I see $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=\infty\cup -\infty$ if you approach to $0$ from left and right side of the real line, so $f$ can not be bounded near $0$ so it has $f$ essential singularity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{z}{1-cos z}=\frac{z}{(z^2/2!)-(z^4/4!)+...}=\frac{1}{(z/2)+O(z^3)}=\frac{2}{z} [\frac{1}{1+O(z^2)}]=\frac{2}{z} ([{1+O(z^2)})^{-1} =\frac{2}{z} [{1-O(z^2)}]=\frac{2}{z}-O(z)$
Thus $$exp [\frac{z}{1-cos z}]=exp[\frac{2}{z}-O(z)]=1+\frac{\frac{2}{z}-O(z)}{1!}+\frac{(\frac{2}{z}-O(z))^2}{2!}+... $$ 
Obviously the above Laurent series expansion of f(z) valid around z=0 i.e. for $0<\vert{z}\vert<\epsilon$ has infinitely many negative (and positive) powers of z. Consequently, z=0 is an essential singularity of f(z).
The correct options are (3) and (4).

Comment: $[1+O(z^2)]^{-1} = 1-O(z^2)$?? Explain this step please

Answer (score 4):

How do you know it isn't a pole? For small $z$, $\frac{z}{1-\cos z}\approx \frac{z}{z^2}=\frac{1}{z}$, so that for small $z$ your function is $\displaystyle  e^{\frac{1}{z}}=\Sigma \frac{1}{n!z^n}$, and this clearly goes to infinity faster than any polynomial goes to $0$, ie. there is no $m$ such that $\,\,\displaystyle  z^m\Sigma \frac{1}{n!z^n}$ is bounded near $0$, hence it is an essential singularity.