# Question regarding essential singular point of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

> How to prove the function $$ f(z)=\exp\Big(\frac{z}{1-\cos z}\Big)$$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$ ?

It's actually hard to express the Laurent series of $f(z)$ around $0$, because the power $\frac{z}{1-\cos z}$ itself is already in the series form (since $\cos z$ appears there and it has the series expansion) and $e^{z/(1-\cos z)}$ has again a series form.

Edit 1: I already see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407318/at-z-0-the-function-fz-expz-over-1-cos-z-has) but it does not give information about the Laurent expension of $f(z)$

Edit 2: How to Proceed or can anyone explain the limit of  $e^{z/(1-\cos z)}$ at $0$ does not exist?

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann conditions do not hold for this function

Comment: @Raffaele Sorry, what?

Comment: Hem, you are not asking any question, are you ?

Comment: For "Edit 2": $f(z)^z=\exp(\frac{z^2}{1-\cos z})$ If $f(0)$ exists, then we get $1$ on the left side. On the right side we get $\frac{z^2}{1-\cos z}|_{z\to 0}=2$ . But we have $1\ne 2$ and therefore the limit cannot exist.

Comment: For "Edit 1": You will not find a "simple" Laurent-series for $f(z)$ but it's enough to know that $f(z)= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!z^n}\left(\frac{z^2}{1-\cos z}\right)^n \approx \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!z^n} =e^{2/z}$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sufficient to prove that the limit $$a = \lim_{z \to 0} \exp \left( \frac{z}{1-\cos z} \right)$$ does not exist, for we have the following trichotomy:

- if $z$ is a removable singularity, the limit exists and $a \in \mathbb{C},$
- if $z$ is a pole, then $a = \infty$ (the complex infinity),
- if $z$ is an essential singularity, the limit does not exist.

Comment: ok. I understand your point of view. But still my question is: How to express $f(z)$ in  the Laurent series form ?

Comment: I have no idea, it seems difficult. But do you have any clue that there exists a closed formula for the expansion?

Comment: No..i have no idea about this.

Comment: Any way, your answer really helps  to identify the singularity quickly. +1

Answer (score 0):

$\exp \left( \frac{z}{1-\cos \left( z \right)} \right)=\exp \left( \frac{2}{z}+\frac{z}{6}+\frac{{{z}^{2}}}{120}+... \right)=\exp \left( \frac{2}{z}+O\left( z \right) \right)=\exp \left( O\left( z \right) \right)\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{2}^{n}}}{n!{{z}^{n}}}}$

...or am i missing something?

**Edit:**  if that's not enough, note:
$$\begin{align}
  & \frac{z}{1-\cos \left( z \right)}=\frac{z}{2}{{\csc }^{2}}\left( \frac{1}{2}z \right)=\frac{z}{2}{{\left( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{n+1}}2\left( {{2}^{2n-1}}-1 \right){{B}_{2n}}}{\left( 2n \right)!}}{{\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)}^{2n-1}} \right)}^{2}} \\ 
 & =\frac{z}{2}{{\left( \frac{2}{z}+\frac{z}{12}+... \right)}^{2}}=\frac{2}{z}{{\left( 1+\frac{{{z}^{2}}}{24}+... \right)}^{2}}=\frac{2}{z}+O\left( z \right) \\ 
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

We wish to show that the function's Laurent series has infinitely many negative terms. As you said, it may be difficult to express the entire Laurent series, but there is a formula for each of the Laurent coefficients:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^{n + 1}}dz$$

where $\gamma$ is a curve around $0$ within an annulus on which $f$ is holomorphic. Perhaps you could try to show that there is no $n < 0$ such that for all $k < n$, $a_k = 0$.